# Calculate conversion percentage in Google Analytics based only on visitors to the page with the conversion action

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, conversions

I have promo website for an app. There is an "Install now" button on the index page, and other pages (such as "tutorial", "private policy", "faq") don't contain the button. 

So I set event tracking for that btn:

```js
gtag('event', 'install', {
    'event_label': 'install_success'
});
```

The problem is that in Google Analytics dashboard I see conversion rate which counts sessions from all pages. Obviously, that number is small and incorrect.

Is there a way to count conversion considering users from index page only?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to see conversion rate just for a page (considering sessions for that page only):

`Behavior -> Site Content -> Landing Pages`

Then choose a page you want to check *(it is just a slash "`/`" in case of index page)*.